# Decoupling caps usb

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

I am trying to understand this circuit from a youtube video from DIYPerks but dont really understand why there are 2200uf caps across usb vin and gnd. So as i understand it they are decoupling caps for inrush current from connection, but according to [THIS](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml) article it seems as though they are supposed to be maximum of 10uF. Could i replace those caps with 10uF caps?
Thanks for any help!

[image: Microphone preamp circuit]

Comment: As anyone can draw anything and put it online for other people to find, if you think you found a poor circuit, you might be correct. The large capacitors on boost converter output also violate the max 10uF suggested maximum, but at least that is limited with 100R in series. So, I don't understand the circuit either. You might want to ask from whoever made the circuit.

Comment: they actually make inrush worse. they are not decoupling caps, they are bulk caps made to smooth out the often noisy 5v coming from USB sources. 10uf would work, just 100/th as effectively (which could be enough). this isn't really a USB(TM) device, it just uses USB for power and as such, doesn't need to confirm to spec limits. Your article talks about oft-ignored  500ma spec limit, but many many usb-connected things use far more current, from flashlights to fans to phones to power banks, etc.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for the great answer it really helped me understand the issue, the purpose of the caps and finding another smaller solution that i think will work great! https://andybrown.me.uk/2015/07/24/usb-filtering/

Comment: search "dc filter" on ebay and buy or make something like that. basically a pi filter with extra caps. they are about the same as what diy perks and your article recommend.

Comment: @dandavis What are the perks with that over the one i linked, less noise, smaller or cheaper?

Comment: the ebay ones have larger inductors and caps and should provide a smoother output than the article's circuit. they are cheap and easy too. i often buy stuff like that and upgrade the caps or connectors as needed, just putting an option out there...

Comment: @dandavis Aa! then i understand, won't work in this case tho since im highly space limited, but good to know for future reference! Should i add any cap to the one i found or do you think it will work?